# Application don't work after downloaded from google play

Tags: android, google-maps

i made an application that based on google maps and when i tried it on my phone from eclipse the app worked fine but when i uploaded it to google play and downloaded it , i could not see the map.
how is that possible? anything i need to do?

those are the permissons:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"></permission>
<uses-feature android:required="true" android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: i could not see the map => Then what's happening exactly? Getting blank map or app is being crashed.

Comment: "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"...do you know why you use it..

Answer (score 2):

make sure your google maps certificate and API key are correct. The one you use to debug and develop should be different from the one you use in your app on the play store

Answer (score 0):

Not sure..but try to add this in your manifest..

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4132500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new API key for your release version.  I assume that you used the SHA1 from the debug.keystore in your .android directory to generate your debug API key.  Essentially you will follow the same steps to create your release key but you need to use the SHA1 from a different keystore.

You mentioned that you used Eclipse so you probably used the `Export Android Application` wizard to generate your apk.  When using that wizard you needed to specify a keystore to sign your apk; so use the SHA1 from that same keystore to generate a release API key.